# How to put $(\cos\theta + j\sin\theta)^6 $ in the form $a+jb$?

Tags: trigonometry, complex-numbers

I am trying to figure out the method to get $(\cos\theta + j\sin\theta)^6 $ in the form $a+jb$ where $j^2=-1$.

I know the answer is $\cos(6 \theta) + j\sin(6\theta) $ but I am unsure of the method.

Comment: More directly, this is [de Moivre's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Moivre%27s_formula).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One may recall that
$$
\cos \theta+ j \sin \theta=e^{j \theta}
$$ giving
$$
\left(\cos \theta+ j \sin \theta\right)^6=e^{j 6\theta}=\cos (6\theta)+ j \sin (6\theta).
$$

Answer (score 2):

$$(\cos\theta + j\sin\theta)^6=e^{6 j\theta}=(\cos6\theta + j\sin6\theta)$$

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming $j = \sqrt{-1}$?

The trick is to repeatedly take advantage of Euler's formula: we have $\Big( \cos(\theta) + j\sin(\theta) \Big)^6 = \Big(e^{j \theta}\Big)^6$, and you can continue from here.

Comment: Yes, the notation $j$ for the imaginary unit is common in physics and electrical engineering.

Answer (score 0):

I would begin with the binomial formula:

$$ (\cos \theta + j \sin \theta)^6 = \sum_{k=0}^6  j^{6-k} \binom{6}{k} \cos^k \theta \sin^{6-k} \theta $$

and use a bunch of identities. This is if you don't want to use de Moivre directly.